# Are there way shorter than this?(Counting number of occurrences of a char in a string in C)

Tags: c++, c

```
int frequence(char *s,char c)
{
    return *s ? (*s==c)+frequence(s+1,c) : 0;
}
```

Are there way shorter than this?

Comment: Rename `frequence` to `f`, and it'll become even shorter.

Comment: Define shorter. Characters? Runtime?

Comment: @Inspired: And even more obscure!

Comment: Do what @Inspired says and remove spaces between operations, i.e. `return *s?(*s==c)+f(s+1,c):0;`. To make it **even** shorter, remove line changes, so you have all code in one line.

Comment: Well, I've added those spaces in `?:` to make it more readable :P

Comment: @莊雅惠 shorter in the sense? we have to paste your 莊雅惠 every time we want to refer you.... ha ha ha.....

Comment: I don't like joke on Chinese characters.@pinkpanther

Answer (score 4):

If you mean by characters, probably. If you mean by runtime? Then you're far from the most optimal solution.

Recursion is vastly slower than looping, and if compiled precisely as written, will use up large quantities of stack space for large enough strings.

Comment: +1 for the stack space. Feed in a large enough chunk of text and it will most likely crash. Sure, a single line probably won't, but it certainly won't accept "all of shakespeares works as one string".

Comment: clang (3.2) transforms the recursion into a loop when optimising. gcc (4.7.2) doesn't, though.

Comment: If Clang does it regardless of optimization flags, then Clang is silly. I agree it's the right thing to do, when optimizing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the function must be named `frequence`, then the iterative way is probably a bit shorter in characters (after removing unnecessary spaces of course):

```
int k=0; while (*s) k += c == *s++; return k;
```

Answer (score 1):

use strchr may get better runtime effiency

```
int frequence(char *s,char c)
{
        char *occur = s;
        int result = 0;
        while((occur = strchr(occur,c))){
                result++;
                occur++;
        }   
        return result;
}
```